# jquery: making button.click & json call work together but keeping them separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, geoip

I have a contact form that encrypts the form *message*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<form name="form_contact" method="post" action="/cgi/formmail.pl">
    // other input fields here

    <textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea>

    <button id="sendbutton" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

The following Javascript script **works** and does things with the form message when people click on the Send-button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button[id$='sendbutton']").click(function(){

    //check if the message has already been encrypted or is empty
      var i = document.form_contact.message.value.indexOf('-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----');
      if((i >= 0) || (document.form_contact.message.value === ''))
        {
            document.form_contact.submit(); return;
        }
      else
        {
            document.form_contact.message.value='\n\n'+ document.form_contact.message.value + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + "--------------------------" + "\n"

            if (typeof(navigator.language) != undefined && typeof(navigator.language) != null) {
                document.form_contact.message.value=document.form_contact.message.value + '\n'+ "Language: " + (navigator.language);}
            else if (typeof(navigator.browserLanguage) != undefined && typeof(navigator.browserLanguage) != null) {
                document.form_contact.message.value=document.form_contact.message.value + '\n'+ "Language: " + (navigator.browserLanguage); }

            // and here's where the geoip service data should be appended to the form message 
            addGEOIPdata();

            //finally the resulting message text is encrypted
            document.form_contact.message.value='\n\n'+doEncrypt(keyid, keytyp, pubkey, document.form_contact.message.value);
        }
    });
}); 


function addGEOIPdata(){
        $.get('http://ipinfo.io', function(response)
        {            
            $("#message").val( $("#message").val() + "\n\n" + "IP: "+ response.ip  + "\n" + "Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.country);
        }, 'jsonp');
};
```

Well, it works except: *it does not add the response from the Geoip service ipinfo.io to the form message* before encrypting it.

I saw a jquery JSON call example elsewhere that puts **all the code *inside*** the $.get('http://ipinfo.io', function(response){...})
but that's *not* what I want. 
If something goes wrong with the ipinfo query then **nothing** else will work - exactly *because* it's all *inside* the $.get('http://ipinfo.io', function(response){...}).

In other words: how can I make my button.click and my $.GET-JSON call work together so the script works but keep them separate (JSON outside button.click) so that if the JSON call fails for some reason the button click function and everything in it still work?

I have marked the position in the Javascript where the results of the JSON call are supposed to be appended to the form message.

Thank you for your help.

---

**EDIT:**

After 1bn hours of trial & error, I eventually stumbled across a way to make it work:

so I put the geoipinfo query into a separate script that gets the info when the page is loading.

```
$.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function (location) {

var results = "\n\n" + "IP: "+ location.ip  + "\n" + "Location: " + location.city + ", " + location.region_name + ", " + location.country_name;

     window.$geoipinfo = results;
 });
```

And then in the other script I posted earlier, I add the variable $geoipinfo to the form message by

```
document.form_contact.message.value=document.form_contact.message.value + §geoipinfo;
```

It seems $geoipinfo is now a global variable and therefore I can use its contents outside the function and in other scripts.

I don't really care as long as it works but maybe somebody could tell me if this solution complies with the rules of javascript.

Comment: It exactly doesn't work because the call to addGEOIPdata is asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

specifies that you can put a handler in .always() and it will be called whether the get succeeds or fails.

```
$.get('http://ipinfo.io', , function(response)
    {            
        $("#message").val( $("#message").val() + "\n\n" + "IP: "+ response.ip  + "\n" + "Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.country);
    }, 'jsonp').always(function(){
        document.form_contact.message.value='\n\n'+doEncrypt(keyid, keytyp, pubkey, document.form_contact.message.value);
    });
```

Comment: If it were me I would be grabbing the IP location on page load so I already had it when it came time to encrypt and submit.

Comment: @Steve I had tried this before but I had difficulties with passing on variables etc. But your comment encouraged me to try it again and it seems to be working now (see EDITed original post). I mark this as the answer. (haven't got enough rep to do anything else anyway :) THANK YOU.